# Best Solution to build SQL Sync-able Schema

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I work on a new project and it uses C#.

I have multiple clients and a server.

Clients uses Service-Based Database MDF & Server uses SQL Server 2014.

I need the best solution to build my schema from scratch to use Microsoft Sync Framework in sync transactions without conflicts like PK or Identity increments.

As an example:

Table customers: id (PK, Identity), name, phone, address

How to make sync share the same information with all clients without making any conflicts or overwriting.

Comment: I used merge replication btween 1 master sql server and sql server on clients. It uses guid to avoid conflicts, but it was hell... good luck

Comment: This sounds like a Bad Idea (tm).  You've got a server, why not use it..?  What problem is the local database supposed to solve?

Comment: I think Local Database is not a bad idea at all, at first it solves a lot of issues like connection stability and huge data caching. Suppose u have a query retrieve more than 100k rows. Please tell me about the performance and internet cost, etc..